# Disable Macros from Safe Mode

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro that now is causing issues with MS Word. I can only open the document in safe mode and cannot figure out how to delete the macro from safe mode. I don't have access to any of the features in safe mode and the macro isn't even showing up. I tried changing the Trust Center settings but none of those options make a difference. Unfortunately I was very dumb and made it a macro on all documents so I can't open any documents without going into safe mode. help!

To be more specific, I believe the code that broke my MS Word was a OnError GoTo ErrorHandler where I tell it to skip to the next if there is an error. I am working on converting equations to a professional format and some of them don't have the right syntax for the conversion so for now I wanted it to ignore those equations and convert the next equation. That is the only change I have made recently that could be the problem.

An additional edit: the macro is coded to run on open. It was running fine before I added the ErrorHandler. I'm sure this is also a huge part of the problem, but a simple solution may not be the right fix since it automatically runs when I open the document. I can't access anything in safe mode.

Comment: Look for a setting to Disable All Macros to prevent them executing. Then you should be able to enter your VBA editor and remove the offending macro

Comment: Also, if you are using Windows, if you are somehow downloading these documents from a repository to your local computer, the you probably need to right-click on the downloaded file and goto Properties and look for the Unblock button. Macros will be blocked unless you Unblock a downloaded file.

Comment: Simply saving the document in the .docx format will delete the macro code.

Comment: Holding the shift or control key down when starting word will disable macros. You will get a dialog box confirming this is what you want before word itself is enabled.

Comment: For clarity: holding down the control key puts Word into Safe Mode. Holding down the shift key prevents `AutoExec` macros from running when Word starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the "Normal" document in the project explorer, resetting it is easy.

[image]

Simply navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Templates` and either delete or rename the Normal.docm file. Once you reopen Word it will regenerate a brand new file automatically - one that contains no code.

[image]

Comment: this did it, thank you so much - you're a lifesaver truly!!!!

Comment: Now, you need to open the old Normal.dotm file while holding down the `Shift` key to keep AutoMacros from running so you can find them. Change the name by adding a "1" or some other character to the end of the name. Then you can change your normal.dotm back and edit your macros. (Holding the Shift key down keeps any Auto... macros from running when the file is opened, not just `AutoExec` but also `AutoOpen` and `AutoNew`.

Answer (score 0):

You created an `AutoOpen` macro which only fires when a document is opened. Presumably this macro is stored in your Normal template.

When you first start Word the macro should not run as you are not opening a document. If Word doesn’t automatically create a new blank document you can safely do so. You will then be able to access and edit the macro you created.